# How to check my Pokémon's attack speed?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a way to check the Pokémon's speed in Pokémon Go?

I noticed that there are variations in the speeds in the attack of the Pokémon (same Pokémon with different speeds).

Does it really happen? Is there a variation by type of attack? If so, how do I check this in the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pokemon Speed does not exist in Pokemon Go. The only stats are Stamina (the equivalent of HP from the main games), Attack (combined physical and special Attack) and Defense (combined physical and special defence).

Variations in the speeds in the attack of the Pokemon are due to differing speeds with the moves they used, not the stats. Pokemon using different moves will have different speeds. The attack speeds cannot be checked in Pokemon Go, but thankfully they have been datamined and can be viewed online. For example here is a list of [fast moves](https://gamepress.gg/pokemongo/pve-fast-moves) and [charge moves](https://gamepress.gg/pokemongo/pve-charge-moves) with their speeds.

Comment: And to add slightly to this, the energy produced in order to use a Charge Move rises at different values.  E.g. on Swampert, having a water move (bubble is it?) fires faster - but raises energy much slower than, say, mud shot, which is a longer animation but fills your energy much faster.